# Add dependencies for different product flavors combinations

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I have my app level **build.gradle** file with multiple product flavors defined. I need to add a dependency only for a combination of product flavors.

My gradle flavors are:

```
flavorDimensions "generic", "custom"
productFlavors {
    clover {
        dimension "custom"
        minSdkVersion 17
    }
    ga {
        dimension "custom"
        minSdkVersion 21
    }
    dit {
        dimension "generic"
        applicationIdSuffix ".dit"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "ADP Time DIT"
    }
    fit {
        dimension "generic"
        applicationIdSuffix ".fit"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "ADP Time FIT"
    }
    iat {
        dimension "generic"
        applicationIdSuffix ".iat"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "ADP Time IAT"
    }
    prodqa {
        dimension "generic"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "ADP Time QA"
    }
    prod {
        dimension "generic"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "ADP Time"
    }
}
```

Now, I need "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5" only for gaDit, gaFit, gaIat, gaProd, gaProdqa flavors.
My dependencies section is:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-background-task')

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    /*changed to accommodate TLSv1 issue. could remove after the issue is fixed in react native*/
//    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'

    implementation project(':react-native-android')

    implementation project(':lottie-react-native')
    implementation project(':react-native-config')
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'

    fitGaImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'

    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')

    implementation project(':react-native-background-timer')

    implementation project(':realm')

    implementation project(':react-native-code-push')
    // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.10.0'
    implementation files('libs/dpuareu.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.8.1.jar')
}
```

But, I'm getting issues with the build, which says "FirebaseInstanceId" is not found.

How to include dependencies for a combination of build variants based on product flavors?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use a combination of flavors in dependencies, you need to add

```
   configurations {
     fitGaImplementation {}
    }
```

to your app's gradle.

in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations) you can see

> "if you want to add a dependency for a variant that combines a
>   product flavor and a build type, then you must initialize the
>   configuration name in the configurations block. ..."